# Pure HTML template solution for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I love HAML, however recently our projects have come under some scrutiny with regards to reliance on non-html structured templates.  I thought I'd take it a step further by asking the question, "How can we use pure HTML design based templates in Ruby on Rails?"

The closest thing I've found so far is a very interesting project that has it's most recent update from 2010 called [***Kwartz***](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/kwartz/) from the author of Erubis.

Is there a project that upholds this pure HTML isolation for designers that is up-to-date and viable on Rails 3.2.x?

Comment: May I ask who criticized your projects for using HAML? Product managers? Designers? Developers? Clients?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter as now project owners have caught hold of it, but initially it was from a couple of designers on the project who are ace designers, but felt using a template language impeded some various styles and tools that they use.  Unfortunately these are likely issues that will not be going away for us and it would be nice to follow this kind of paradigm that the author of Kwartz set forth as I certainly could work within those parameters (especially with something a little more up-to-date and clean).

Comment: Why not use ERB? The standard template of rails

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu refer to the arguments in the presentation with Kwartz to see why that's not the *optimal* solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your designers are correct that HAML does not have widespread HTML tool support.

A really excellent solution IMHO is Handlebars. It is simpler than HAML, and will work with more HTML tools because Handlebars emphasizes moving code out of the page template and into the controller. This also is good for writing maintainable pages with designers and also for security.

Handlebars is led by Yehuda Katz, who helped write Rails 3, is a core contributor to JavaScript, and is currently working on Ember.js which also leverages Handlebars.

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Hmm, this very nearly [reminds me of Liquid](http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid) in terms of it's conventions. Having used Liquid myself before, I was never a big fan of it.  But Handlebars is a good suggestion since this would be a fairly universal template solution that would work in Rails and Tower.js,due to its use of Ember, etc.  Hmm.

Comment: @ylluminate I've used Liquid too, and Handlebars is similar in the sense that the markup is easier for designers. The big difference IMHO is that Handlebars is purposefully designed to work with many languages.

Comment: You know, I think you're primarily right about the handlebars approach. It would be more "universal."  It's had me looking though and I almost want to tell them to stuff it and just accept SLIM as that seems even slicker than HAML from some of what I've seen.  LOL.

Answer (score -1):

You are either going to do something with the templates, right? As in, the designer gives you the template, you strip out the parts that already belong to `app/views/layouts/application`, inject the necessary ruby to get your data into the view etc.

So what's the problem? Let the designers provide their templates in HTML, you convert them to HAML when using in the app, instead of converting them to ERB.

Comment: Well I think the presentation that Makoto makes here really answers this: http://www.slideshare.net/kwatch/how-to-make-designerfriendly-template-engine

Comment: Well I think that giving still another (domain-specific) language (kwartz) to learn instead of using any other, is not a solution. If you can live with client-side templates, then neither ERB nor HAML is a solution (and develop all your app in JS using ember, angular, whatever). But you asked for an alternative to ERB/HAML, so it's server side. You are going to convert html to haml, kwartz to ERB, it's still a separate step. What's the point in fixing it then?